# Firebase app timestamp (not local)

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, timestamp

I am building an app using Android Studio and Firebase. When the user stores a certain object in the database I want a timestamp in milliseconds to be generated. However, I want this timestamp to be NOT local, so that users cannot influence the timestamp by modifying their device's time. Is there a nice way to do this?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it is. To achieve this, just simply use: `ServerValue.TIMESTAMP`.

But remember, when you set the `TIMESTAMP` in your database, you set it as a `Map` and when you retrieve it, you retrieve it as a `Long`. So you are retrieving those `milliseconds` that were talking about. And because this is the server `TIMESTAMP`, it cannot be modified by user devices.

If you are using a model class, the `TIMESTAMP` field should look like this:

```
private Map<String, String> timestamp;
```